# add page id to javascript href

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a generic menu work across hundreds of sub-sites in an educational CMS from an external JS file. In any sub-site I need the siteID

eg path.to/query?siteID=12345

to the set of generic urls (eg eg path.to/query?siteID=replace) in the js file which is called from the sub-sites homepage. The CMS would handle this string replacement for other pages inside the sub-sites, just not on the homepage.
Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
var href = window.location.href; //This will give the current page href
var regex = new RegExp("siteID=([^&])+");
var newhref = href.replace(regex, "siteId=" + newId)
```

Comment: Why `var regex` ? what are `a` and `newId`

Comment: regex and a is fixed. newId is the id of the menu item needed.

Comment: many thanks. So **var newref** will hold the siteID extracted from the site's url. Now to get that into the href="javascript: .... what is the form of the reference to the var in the url after "href="javascript:? Does it need escape characters? the url will be relative eg '/dir/dir/siteID=

Comment: you can narrow it down and use `window.location.search` which will only look on the query part of the URL